# Execute <script> tags in react component which comes from markdown syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I have a restAPI where I store my post content with markdown syntax. What I want to achieve is to manually place script tags in the content for my Gists and for Google AdSense. In my react app I'm using [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown) to convert the markdown into HTML format. With *'escapeHtml'* option set to *false* the react-markdown executes the scripts and shows my ads, gists properly but only when the page first loaded. Whenever I navigate somewhere else with react-router it still renders but not executes the scripts.

I appreciate any help